# File open notification

Tags: linux, unix

Is there a way to be notified/trigger a script when a particular file is opened for reading or writing? I'm not specifically thinking of security but if anyone knows any linux/unix security mechanisms that can accomplish the same thing that will also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep - [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) uses the kernel's [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) mechanism, and will do exactly what you want. It's like "regular" cron, but instead of triggering jobs at certain time intervals, it triggers jobs based on filesystem changes.